# Problem when creating object of a subclass

Tags: python-3.x, class, super

I am trying to run this code:

```
class Animal:
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
    c = 10

    
class Mammal(Animal):
        def __init__(self, parent, e, f):
                super().__init__(parent, a, b)
                self.e = e
                self.f = f

        g = 11

snake = Animal(3, 4)

cat = Mammal(6, 7, 8, 9)
```

But I get the following message:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Users\Andrea\Desktop\Python tutorials\super()_2_NotWorking!!!.py",
> line 18, in 
> cat = Mammal(6, 7, 8, 9) TypeError: **init**() takes 4 positional arguments but 5 were given

Please, could you help me figure out what mistake I made?

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a misunderstanding here of how subclasses work.

For your base class:

```
class Animal:
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
    c = 10
```

`Animal` would be instantiated like so.

```
snake = Animal(3, 4)
```

Where `3` is passed to the `__init__` `a` argument and `4` to `b`.

Now to your subclass.
You have:

```
class Mammal(Animal):
    def __init__(self, parent, e, f):
        super().__init__(parent, a, b)
        self.e = e
        self.f = f

    g = 11
```

This doesn't make much sense because the base class `Animal` only takes 2 arguments in it's `__init__` method (other than the the implicitly added `self`) and you are calling it with 3.

```
super().__init__(parent, a, b)
```

`super()` here roughly translates to the `self` of my parent (`Animal`) class.
Additionally, `a` and `b` aren't assigned to anything at this point.

What you were probably intending to do is something like this.

```
class Animal:
    def __init__(self, a, b):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b
    c = 10

    
class Mammal(Animal):
    def __init__(self, a, b, e, f):
        # Here we call the Animal().__init__()
        # with the a and b arguments that were passed
        # from cat = Mammal(6, 7, 8, 9)
        super().__init__(a, b)
        self.e = e
        self.f = f
    g = 11

snake = Animal(3, 4)

cat = Mammal(6, 7, 8, 9)
print(cat.a, cat.b)
```

Answer (score 1):

`parent` in `__init__` method of `Mammal` class is just a normal argument and it does not represent the `Animal` class.

So that, this `__init__` method will have 4 arguments: `self`, `parent`, `e`, `f`.

That's the reason why when you call `Mammal(6, 7, 8, 9)` it raises an error because you called 5 arguments: `Mammal class itself`, `6`, `7`, `8`, `9`.

This code will not cause the error:

```
class Animal:
  def __init__(self, a, b):
    self.a = a
    self.b = b
  c = 10

    
class Mammal(Animal):
  def __init__(self, a, b, e, f):
    super().__init__(a, b)
    self.e = e
    self.f = f

  g = 11

snake = Animal(3, 4)
cat = Mammal(6, 7, 8, 9)
```

Repl.it example [here](https://replit.com/join/yljzzdka-diemthanhthanh)